# Restart loader in fragment from dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have an `Activity` which contains a `Fragment` with a `Loader`.  I'm attempting to restart the loader depending on the result of a`DialogFragment` but can't work out how to access it.  Given that the dialog fragment is spawned from the activity and so separate from the fragment containing the loader, how to I access it?  I assume that I can do something to go through the activity, but not sure what.

Comment: You can use an Interface for communicating between fragments. Thats what the Android doc also suggests. Here's a cool video on the same. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8  -- Also if you could post your code?

Comment: I was hoping there would be something a bit more structured than using interfaces and casting `getActivity()`, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Interface are indeed the good way as they will help you add any number of methods in the same interface allowing back and forth communication in a more flexible manner. See how it goes eventually. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not opening the dialog from the fragment itself?

Try opening the dialog fragment from the fragment with the Loader, pass an interface to the constructor on when the dialog is dismissed call the callback function...simple as is

Comment: The dialog is triggered from a menu option which is attached to the activity, so unfortunately I can't do that.